# How would I create a git stash and keep working with the files I have stashed?

Tags: git

I would like to use a git stash to create a copy of my code as of today. I would also like to continue working with the code. Is there a way to create a stash without removing the stashed files from your work area?

Comment: why specifically a stash, a branch would seem more appropriate

Comment: All `git stash` does is make some commits. The commits it makes are not on any branch, but you could just as easily—or *more* easily, really—make ordinary commits on an ordinary branch, after which they're a whole lot easier to work with. It's usually more sensible to do that. I recommend avoiding `git stash` as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this

```
git stash
git stash apply
```

Comment: I don't use stash nearly as often as I should does git stash apply, not just pop the code changes from the stash? It leaves them there to be pop'ed again?

Comment: @Jcrash29 `git stash pop` removes the stash from the stash list and applies it on the current working tree. However, `git stash apply` just applies the stash from the stash list.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```sh
git add -A  # If you want to stash untracked files too
git stash  # Create a copy of your code
git stash apply  # Similar to git stash pop, but your stash is not removed
```

Then you can keep working on your files, and you can still see your stash in `git stash list` and apply it again using its ID:

```
$ git stash list
stash@{0}: WIP on master: bff15a90f Last commit message
$ git stash apply 0
```

Finally, when you want to get rid of the stash, you can use:

```
git stash drop 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you don't just create a branch?

```
git branch currentCode
```

This will create a new branch with your code as committed, and allow you to continue working.

Edit:
It sounds like maybe you don't have the code committed. Perhaps:

```
git add -u
git commit -m 'a backup of my code as of March 27'
git branch march27
```

After that your code is committed and you can continue to work with it, but if everything you do in the following days, you can delete it all and feel confident that your code is still commited.

Comment: Should be `git branch -b currentCode` (note the **-b**) to create a *new* branch

Comment: -b would move him from (I assume) master to currentCode. It's possible thats not what he wants.

Comment: @alan.elkin `git branch x` (without `-b`) creates the branch and stays on the current branch. `git checkout -b x` creates the branch and checks it out, maybe that's where you got `-b` from :)